# Opening an image using ImageTk in Pillow causing an AttributeError and RuntimeError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am using Pillow 7.1.2 in Python 3.8.2. I have had problems opening images using the Image.open and ImageTk.PhotoImage methods to open images to use in Tkinter programs. This is the most simple way to import images I can think of which I have written into my scratch file and I am getting an AttributeError and a RuntimeError.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

image = Image.open("0.gif")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```

As far as all sources I can find go, this code should work, but it doesn't. Am I missing something incredibly obvious? The errors are as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cassi/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmEdu2020.1/scratches/scratch.py", line 4, in <module>
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
  File "C:\Users\cassi\PycharmProjects\Temp\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 112, in __init__
    self.__photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(**kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4061, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3994, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError('Too early to create image')
RuntimeError: Too early to create image
Exception ignored in: <function PhotoImage.__del__ at 0x000001ADDF06B5E0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cassi\PycharmProjects\Temp\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 118, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

How would I fix this? Is there something wrong with my code, or is the problem something else? Thanks!

Comment: You can't create PhotoImages until after you've called `Tk()`.  The environment that the images will live in doesn't even exist until that point.

Comment: There are nearly two dozen questions on this site related to that exact error. Did none of those help you answer your question? How is this question different from those?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

canvas = Canvas(Tk(),width=200,height=200)
canvas.pack()

image = Image.open("0.gif") # Convert to PIL image

pimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image) # Convert to PhotoImage

canvas.create_image(100,100,image=pimage)
```

Answer (score 0):

`tkinter` raises an error when you didn't create a window(`tkinter.Tk` Object) before creating an `ImageTk.PhotoImage` Object.
Try this code, its working:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter 
#don't use "from tkinter import *" because tkinter also has an Image object and things will get mixed up
window = tkinter.Tk()
#Now you can create an Photo Image in PIL
img = Image.open("0.gif")
tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
label1 = tkinter.Label(window, image = tkimg)
label1.pack()
```

If that also does'nt work, maybe you just downloaded a e. '0.jpg' picture and renamed it to '0.gif'.
[Here's the link](https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-gif) for converting to .gif online or here's the PIL code:

```py
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("0.jpg")
img.save("0.gif", "gif") # Signature of function: Image().save(name, type)
```

Comment: @Cassidy If that's to not working please leave your os name and your python version so that I can try another answer.